# ordering 2 tables by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to order 2 tables by date, but the problem is sql is not ordering them simultaneously.

here is my query:

```
SELECT users_id,CONCAT_WS(' ', users_fname, users_lname)
 AS full_name, reply_message, concern_message
FROM tbl_usersinfo AS i 
LEFT JOIN tbl_concern AS c
 ON c.student_id = i.users_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_reply_concern AS r 
ON r.student_id = i.users_id 
ORDER BY c.date,r.date
```

I read that i need to put ISNULL(c.date,r.date) but its not working.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? You don't even show the fields on which you have sorted so how can you know?

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve. Can you provide sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ifnull` or `coalesce`

```
SELECT users_id,
       CONCAT_WS(' ', users_fname, users_lname) AS full_name,
       reply_message,
       concern_message
  FROM tbl_usersinfo AS i
  LEFT JOIN tbl_concern AS c
    ON c.student_id = i.users_id
  LEFT JOIN tbl_reply_concern AS r
    ON r.student_id = i.users_id
 ORDER BY ifnull(c.date, r.date)
```

The MySQL equivalent of ISNULL (in SQL Server) is IFNULL. In MySQL I believe ISNULL is just a test of whether something is or is not null which would evaluate to 0 or 1.